# How to type Generic Function Parameters for wrapping a callback style function into a more Promise style?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a generic that handles translating a callback into a synchronous-style function call.

For example. `f(err: Error, response: ResponseT):void` should become `f(): ResponseT`

How could I accomplish that?

I have a function called wrap() that already does that.. how do I declare it properly so it preserves types?

Trying something like

`function wrapAsync<A extends any[], E, R>(f: (...args: A, err: E, response: R) => void): R`

But that doesn't work clearly because REST args have to come after any others.

Comment: I found something like this: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/util.promisify/index.d.ts

Seems like the only way to accomplish this is to use an ugly hack ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but a bit tricky

1. Get number of last argument. Most trickiest part, as TS doesn't allow arithmetic for types. So we convert function to function with specific first argument. Then `...args` become array with length decreased by 1. Then we infer length of `...args` array.

   ```
   type GetLastArgNum<F extends ((...args: any[]) => any)> = 
     F extends ((p1: any, ...args: infer R) => any) ? 
     R extends { length: infer L } ? L : never : never;
   ```
2. Get type of last arg.

   ```
   type GetLastArgType<F extends ((...args: any[]) => any)> = Parameters<F>[GetLastArgNum<F>]
   ```
3. And finally convert to desired function type

   ```
   type TransformFunction<F extends ((...args: any[]) => any)> = (() => GetLastArgType<F>)
   ```

And to apply to your task. If I understand correctly, you need function `wrapAsync` which will accept callback function and return function which does not have any arguments but returns value of last argument type. It will look like

```
function wrapAsync<F extends ((...args: any[]) => any)> (f: F): (() => GetLastArgType<F>)
```

[TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIHFqgDIEMDOoCCAnA5gHICuAtgDwBis0AHqNAHYAm6sAFGwHTer7oBcsVA3ABtALoBKWAF4AfEJGSFM2MFiwqtes1YdIARkHDwAGljdOvPANgBLBgDNoOWACVp8xeGkB+NRpu1HSMLLAA3rAANox4oAAWgg7OrsiwAL6w-mmCDNAAbi6wuQUuANwgEDAISGiYuHgAKlDQlME6YRyW1rYmEp4KJsqysAAKvKgkSC7olHKiiCgY2PjE5BRy4mAtsI04wuiOAPY4JBREDADGoHZHDG3aoXpcPHzGIv2yg0oq7GwDNSW9XwzRgc0kIGADnoOEcqEucAAkgYIrBIDgjoZBJgcA48BlttUAEZEkZ7A7HU7nK43O5kDg4bGgXEMPDmfK5UhElzmSCCZEA-JHOxMZRAA)

Comment: Wow, that's a little mind blowing! :) How do I then apply that type to my real function wrap() for example?